# dl(detail list) not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

dl list view not working in bootstrap 4 same as it does in bootstrap 3

HTML:

```
 <section class="landing">
      <div class="container">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
          <dt>col1</dt>
          <dd>col2</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That class has been removed from Bootstrap in V4.

From the [Migration documents of Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)

> `.dl-horizontal` has been dropped. Instead, use `.row` on `<dl>` and use grid column classes (or mixins) on its `<dt>` and `<dd>` children.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D.. :)

Answer (score 30):

I had the same exact problem and solved it using `.row` class as suggested by @Paulie_D

Here is what I did

```
 <section class="landing">
  <div class="container">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-3">col1</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-9">col2</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**
You can also add text align right and left

```
 <section class="landing">
  <div class="container">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-3 text-right">col1</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-9 text-left">col2</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Doesn't `.dl-horizontal` text align right when in-line and then align-left when block?

Comment: If we have multiple dt-dd pairs, how to have each of them on its own row?

Answer (score 12):

If you've embedded `.dl-horizontal` in content, you could always add the Bootstrap 3 code back into your own `.css` stylesheets. From the [Bootstrap 3 source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1454):

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 180px;
  }
}

...

.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after, {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

...

.dl-horizontal dd:after {
  clear: both;
}
```